# Pronunciation of "the East" in the Carol "The First Noel"

Tags: pronunciation, definite-articles, lyrics

I sing in a choir and most of us are Spanish speakers. We're singing *The First Noel*, and last night someone questioned whether we should say "the East" pronounced as "thuh East" or "thee East."

The lyrics read:

> They looked up and saw a star
>   shining in the East beyond them far
>   And to the earth it gave great light
>   And so it continued both day and night.

I looked up the rule, and it's not clear to me, as I cannot identify whether the 'e' in East is considered a consonant or a vowel sound. Compare 'East' and 'earth'. In the latter, it is clear that the pronunciation should be "thee earth", but the sound of 'e' in 'East' is different, so what should it be?

Also, when I looked up the song sang by other choirs, they say "thee East."

Can you please help and provide the rule that should be followed in this specific case or is it a case of poetic license?

Comment: Closely related: *[The + vowel letter](/questions/131354)* and *[Is pronouncing “The” as in “Thee” still correct in titles?](/questions/5795)* Also see *[The pronunciation of the definite article by American speakers](/questions/286987)*, *[Variations in the pronunciation of “the”](/questions/191979)*, and *[What is the pronunciation of “the”?](/questions/1082)*

Comment: https://youtu.be/D5uud2fjtoo?t=55s

Comment: Appears to be an opinion-based question to me.

Comment: There is a rule for normal speech, thee before vowels, thuh before consonants. But in song or poetry, it depends on meter, accent, or even arbitrary artifice.

Comment: Your "the East" should always be pronounced [ðiʔˈist] or [ðiˈjist], but the duplicates may be hard to find.

Comment: @tchrist It's certainly possible to say [ðɪː ɪːst] with no [ʔ] or [j]. I would go so far as to say it's standard British English.

Comment: I don't understand why you think linking the title to the full lyrics would be biased (according to your [edit notes](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/417416/6)). There is no indication or instruction as to how *the* in "the East" or "the earth" should be pronounced.

Comment: @Hellion It is not at all a duplicate. However *the east* may be pronounced in speaking, this has little to do with how it is sung.

Comment: Do not use comments to answer (post an [answer](/help/how-to-answer) instead), praise or rebuke ([vote](/help/why-vote) instead), discuss ([chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead), suggest edits ([edit](/help/privileges/edit) instead), or comment on site design or policy (post at [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead). Use comments to [ask for clarification, suggest changes, or offer short-lived information](/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Case of poetic license

I’m a native English speaker and have sung that carol most of my life

When we sing it it’s most like:
Thee ee-eest

Answer (score -1):

"East" begins with a vowel sound.  You say "Thee East", not "Thuh East".  You would say "Thuh West"